# Activity- BADGES wired style

Tags: bug, activity-badges

I insert to my Activity section and look at this...
The `BADGES` section height is too long and up on the tabs section (I use Google Chrome).

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *"I insert to my Activity section"*?